# How to accept Apple Pay with Stripe JS inside WKWebView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm trying to load up a webpage which uses  Stripe.js inside a WKWebView on iOS (using Xamarin.Forms).

Everything works fine (can take card payments), except for Apple Pay: paymentRequest.canMakePayment() always returns null.

The same webpage inside a SFSafariViewController works fine, so the issue seems to be related to restrictions inside WKWebView.
However, according to https://webkit.org/blog/9674/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13/ this should now be supported and indeed the same WKWebView also loads up the official Apple Pay demo page (https://applepaydemo.apple.com/) with no issues.

It would seem that the problem is eventually with how Stripe.js works under the hood (perhaps with regards to script injection).

My custom renderer in Xamarin looks like this:

```
        WKWebView wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NativeWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                wkWebView.WeakNavigationDelegate = new WebNavigationDelegate();
                SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url)));
        }
```

And the JS in the webpage (taken from the Stripe Element samples):

```
            //set up payment request
            var paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
                country: 'GB',
                currency: 'gbp',
                total: {
                    label: 'sample order',
                    amount: 100,
                },
                requestPayerName: true,
                requestPayerEmail: true,
            });

            paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function (result) {
                // result is always false!
                ...
            });
```

Are there perhaps additional settings that can be added to the WKWebView to make this work?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Apple Pay is only supported in an SFSafariViewController. I see that you say it does seem to work, but that's news to me. If you think it's a bug with Stripe you should write to their support.

Comment: In iOS, Apple Pay is supported in `Safari` and in `SFSafariViewController` objects.Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web

Comment: Well according to the article I linked "In iOS 13, webpages loaded in WKWebView can now accept Apple Pay.". This seems to be confirmed by their demo page working OK. I'm guessing it's then an issue with the Stripe component in this case.

Comment: You could post the issue to https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/issues .

Comment: I've contacted Stripe support and they also believe that there is something specific inside stripe.js library's wrapping functions that cause canMakePayment to return false in the WebView. I'll post here once I hear back from them with a potential solution/workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. It was acknowledged by Stripe as a flaw in their JS wrapper and has been fixed in recent updates to the official library.